# Is HTML5 supported

Tags: html, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a website where I can see which HTML 5 tags are supported in in different browsers? And WebGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292672/is-there-a-website-where-i-can-see-which-html-5-tags-are-supported-in-in-differe)

Is HTML5 supported by all browsers? What is the story? Just some tags aren't? Is there any list of what which browser support?

I have one project on my hands and I am hesitating between HTML5 and HTML 4.

Comment: [www.caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com)  Search for whatever feature you want.

Comment: You should certainly use the HTML5 doctype (works even in IE6). Besides that, you can decide which features you use from HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some parts are supported, some parts are not - wich parts differs from browser to browser. for a nice overview, take a look at [caniuse.com about HTML5](http://www.caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5).

Answer (score 2):

No, not all browsers support the full HTML5 draft.

IE6, 7, an 8 are all still very popular, as are many older versions of Firefox and Safari and other browsers, none of which support the full html5 draft.

That being said, the  most important thing is to *test* on the browsers and platforms you wish to support!

In all cases, write the most current code you can and then "backport" it in as easy a way possible to deal with older browsers not being able to handle the newer elements. It is much easier to strip out un-needed crutches when older browsers go away than it is to re-write stuff to be more modern.

Comment: No browsers currently fully supports the HTML5 specification.

Comment: HTML5 has not reached recommendation status either.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty detailed chart: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/

Answer (score 1):

HTML5  is still under development. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5). So I will suggest you go with HTML4. Otherwise you will have to update your application if any feature is updated or removed.

Almost all latest browsers support HTML5 (IE10, Chrome 16, FF), but old version of same browsers doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with whats is simple and works with legacy HTML/CSS, and if you want some more, do it right, knowing if the browser has the capabilities.

I suggest you to take a look at http://www.modernizr.com/, it can help you to achieve your goals, respecting legacy support.

Check this article an understand how you can use it http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/

Hope that helps!